# Django: Refresh captcha form

Tags: python, django

I have a registration form with multiple fields and captcha form. I'm new to django-simple-captcha, and I made a refresh button to only refresh the captcha alone. Is it possible to do that? How should I write the function?

*register.html*

```
<div><input type="text" name="studentId"></div>
<div><input type="text" name="Name"></div>
...
<div>{{ form.captcha }}</div>
<button type="button" class="btn">Refresh</button> // refresh captcha
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

*forms.py*

```
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

*views.py*

```
from .forms import MyForm

def preRegistration(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'registration_form.html', {"form": form})
    if request.method == 'POST':
       studentId = request.POST.get('studentId') ... 
       if form.is_valid():
          Applicant.objects.create(studentID=studentID, ...)
          return render(request, 'login.html')
       else: 
          messages.error(request, 'Wrong Captcha!')
          return render(request, 'registration.html', {"form": form})

def refreshCaptcha():
    ...
```

Comment: Should be an ajax view/Json response updated on a some action like button click

Comment: @ViaTech I'll check about that. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

django-simple-captcha provide the code for refreshing the captcha on button click.

You can do something like this.

## html:

```
<form action='.' method='POST'>
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" />
    <button class='js-captcha-refresh'></button>
</form
```

## javascript:

```
$('.js-captcha-refresh').click(function(){
    $form = $(this).parents('form');

    $.getJSON($(this).data('url'), {}, function(json) {
        // This should update your captcha image src and captcha hidden input
    });
    return false;
});
```

For more details check this url [django_simple_captcha](https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: Yeah, this is directly showing from the docs what you need to do. May need to make some edits to ensure it works for your needs, but should be pretty straightforward

Comment: I'll definitely try this. Thank you so much.